# android - Program type already present: android.support.multidex.ZipUtil$CentralDirectory

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I use the following way for adding the `multidex` in my project but i come across with the following error

> Error: Program type already present:
>   android.support.multidex.ZipUtil$CentralDirectory

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.7"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "12g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'        
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    ......
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex

        // optional
        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
    minSdkVersion =19
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

multidex.keep

```
android/support/multidex/BuildConfig/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V19/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V4/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor$1/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor/class
android/support/multidex/ZipUtil$CentralDirectory/class
android/support/multidex/ZipUtil/class
```

AppController.java

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
   }
}
```

can anyone help me
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android studio to build project.

Please run from menu

Build-> Clean Project

And than rebuild the project

I was getting the such error with other libraries. It got solved by using the above mentioned steps.